# Closed form for $(p-n)!\pmod{p}$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

Does $(p-n)!\pmod{p}$ have a closed form for any $n>2$ when $p$ is prime?

- $(p-0)!=0 \pmod{p}$
- $(p-1)!=-1\pmod{p}$
- $(p-2)!=1\pmod{p}$

Comment: from $(p-1)!$ to $\Big(p-(p-1)\Big)$, we just traverse the reduced residue system modulo $p$. Kind of hard to say which permutation of it is encountered.

Comment: You'd need to find a formula for the multiplication inverse of $n!\pmod p$.  Then $(p-n)! \equiv (-1)^{n} (n-1)!^{-1}\pmod p$ or something like that.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461331/prove-p-kk-1-equiv-1k-text-mod-p.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p$, $$(p-n)! \equiv  \frac{(p-1)!}{\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (p-j)}  \equiv (-1)^{n-1} ((n-1)!)^{-1} \mod p$$

Comment: For example: $(p-4)!\equiv (3!)^{-1}\mod p$. ** what is** $(3!)^{-1}\mod p$? Is it is equal to $(6\mod p)^{-1}$ that is multiplicative inverse of $6$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ?

Comment: Sir, I thing something wrong with the formula. By above closed form formula: $98!\equiv (-1)^2 (2!)^{-1}\mod 101$ that is $98!\equiv (2)^{-1}\mod 101$ that implies $98!\equiv 51\mod 101$. However this is not true! Since $98!\equiv 50\mod 101$

Answer (score 5):

The only interesting case is $n=1$, which is [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

The case $n=2$ follows from $n=1$ directly.

For the case $n=3$ one needs to know the multiplicative inverse of $p-2 \bmod p$, which is $(p-1)/2$. So, $(p-3)! \equiv (p-1)/2 \bmod p$.

For the case $n=4$ one needs to know the multiplicative inverse of $p-3 \bmod p$. Now $p=3t\pm1$, assuming $p\ne3$. Then $(p-4)! \equiv (p\mp 1)(p-1)/6\bmod p$.

I guess you could carry on but it seems to get messier...

Comment: You can write the inverse of $p-3$ as $\frac{p^2-1}3$ if you want to eliminate the $\pm 1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, good point.

Comment: See also [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/256780/242)