# Closed form for $(p-4)!$ and $(p-3)!$ via Wilson's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I would like to use Wilson's Theorem to compute

$(p - 4)! \mod p$

I've gotten as far as

$(p - 4)! \cdot (p-3) \cdot (p-2) \cdot (p-1) \equiv (p - 1) \pmod p$

However I can't figure out how to isolate

$(p - 4)! \mod p$

Comment: @lhf But that doesn't give the nice closed form possible here.

Comment: @Bill, my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/99879/589) does.

Comment: @lhf But that's not as nice as what's below. It has $\rm\:(p\mp 1)(p-1)/6\:$ vs. $\rm\:(1\mp p)/6\:$ below.

Comment: I think it's dumb to close specific questions because the more general question has already been treated.  I think perhaps that's what Bill is saying above as well.

Comment: @Graphth Generally I think it's good to close special-case dupes. My point was simply that the answer there can be simplified. I didn't recall the prior question when I composed my reply. At least we got something good from it (a simpler result).

Comment: @lhf You might find of interest the note I added to my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving linear congruences by hand: modular fractions and inverses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174676/solving-linear-congruences-by-hand-modular-fractions-and-inverses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Wilson reflection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24095/242) $\rm\ mod\ p\!:\: -1 \equiv (p\!-\!1)! = \overbrace{(p\!-\!1)(p\!-\!2)(p\!-\!3)(p\!-\!4)!}^{\textstyle \equiv (-1)\ (-2)\ (-3)\ (p\!-\!4)!}\equiv -6(p\!-\!4)!$

But for $\rm\:p \ne 2,3,\: \ \ 2\cdot 3 = 6\:$ will be invertible mod $\rm\:p,\:$ so $\rm\:(p-4)! \equiv 1/6\pmod p$

Furthermore, notice $\rm\ \ p = 6\:k\pm 1\:\Rightarrow\:\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{(p\!-\!4)!\,\equiv\, 1/6\, \equiv  (1\mp p)/6},\, $ where $\rm\,6\mid 1\mp p$

Similarly $\,-1 \equiv (p\!-\!1)! = 2(p\!-\!3)! \Rightarrow \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\rm(p\!-\!3)! \equiv -1/2 \equiv (p\!-\!1)/2},\,$ where $\rm\,2\mid p\!-\!1$

**Note** $\:$ The signed-equation denotes two equations: the top sign case, and bottom sign case.
$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\:p = 6\:\!k{\color{#c00}{+1}}\: &\Rightarrow& \rm\:(p-4)!\equiv 1/6\equiv (1+{\color{#c00}{(-1)}} p)/6&\rm\quad top\ signs \\ 
\rm\:p = 6\:\!k{\color{#c00}{-1}}\: &\Rightarrow &\rm\:(p-4)!\equiv 1/6\equiv (1+{\color{#c00}{(+1)}} p)/6&\rm\quad bottom\ signs \end{eqnarray}$$
Indeed, we seek $\rm\:x\:$ so $\rm\:6\:|\:1+x\:\!p,\:$ or $\rm\:mod\ 6\!:\: -1\equiv x\:\!p \equiv x\!\:s,\:$ where $\rm\:\color{#c00}s = (p\ mod\ 6),\,$ by [inverse reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242). So $\rm\:x \equiv -1/s.\:$ Here $\rm\:s\equiv \pm1\:\Rightarrow\:s^2 = 1\:\Rightarrow\: -1/s = -s/s^2 = -s,\:$ so
$$\rm\:p = 6\:\!k+{\color{#c00}{s}}\: \Rightarrow\: (p-4)!\equiv 1/6\equiv (1+{\color{#c00}{(-s)}}\:\! p)/6\quad abstract\ sign$$
Hence the equation that I wrote above involving the signs $\pm$ and $\mp,$ denotes two equations, the case $\rm\:s = 1\:$ of above (choose all the top signs) and case $\rm\:s = -1\:$ (choose all the bottom signs). Indeed, if we substitute $\rm\: s = \pm 1\:$ then $\rm -s = \mp 1,\:$ so we obtain said equation with signs.

Such expressions can be given a rigorous algebraic interpretation by working in certain quotient rings,$\:\!$ i.e.  modulo $\rm\:s^2 = 1.\:$ Namely $\rm\:R[s]/(s^2-1) \cong R[s]/(s-1) + R[s]/(s+1)\cong R^2.\:$ Hence arithmetic in $\rm\:R\:$ with adjoined sign $\rm\:s\:$ is isomorphic to arithmetic of pairs of elements of $\rm\:R,\:$ where the first component denotes the universe where $\rm\:s = 1\:$ and the second where $\rm\:s = -1.\:$

Beware, however, that sometimes such signed expressions denote the set of equations resulting from *all* possible combinations of signs. In this case one adjoins multiple sign indeterminates $\rm\:s_i\:$ such that $\rm\:s_i^2 = 1.\:$ One often needs to infer from the context which denotation is intended.

Comment: What's the difference between using $\pm$ and $\mp$

Comment: @johnthexiii I've added a detailed explanation.

Comment: that was very thorough

Answer (score 0):

You can use the facts that $p-k \equiv -k \mod p$. Then you have to decide whether the product is invertible.