# Prove $(p-k)!(k-1)!\equiv (-1)^k \text{ mod p }$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is a question from my number theory class.

Prove 
$$(p-k)!(k-1)!\equiv (-1)^k \text{ mod p} $$
Help please!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Please share what you've tried and what's giving you difficulty, as well as what you do understand about the problem. This way, people can give help that's actually relevant to you.

Comment: Have you heard of Wilson's theorem?

Comment: Seems like a good candidate for induction...

Comment: @Ethan: lhf's answer could be written more succinctly as:
$$
(p-1)!(1-1)!\equiv(-1)^1\pmod{p}\qquad\text{Wilson's Theorem}
$$
Suppose that $(p-k)!(k-1)!\equiv(-1)^k\pmod{p}$ for some $k$, then
$$
\begin{align}
(p-k-1)!k!
&=(p-k-1)!k(k-1)!\\
&\equiv-(p-k-1)!(p-k)(k-1)!\pmod{p}\\
&=-(p-k)!(k-1)!\\
&\equiv(-1)^{k+1}\pmod{p}
\end{align}
$$
thus, it is true for all $k\ge1$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99876/closed-form-for-p-n-pmodp-where-p-is-prime.

Comment: See aso [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/256780/242)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$(p-k)!\ (k-1)! =$

$= (p-k)!\ (1\cdot 2\cdots (k-1))$

$\equiv (p-k)!\ ((p-1)\cdot (p-2)\cdots (p-(k-1))(-1)^{k-1}\ $ (because $p-t\equiv -t$)

$ = (p-1)! \ (-1)^{k-1} \equiv (-1)^k\bmod p$

Wilson's theorem is used in the last step.

So, this result is actually equivalent to Wilson's theorem, which is the case $k=1$.