# MODULAR problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What will be the remainder when 64! is divided by 71?

Do we need to solve this problem by using MOD theorem or need to expands the factorial?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99876/closed-form-for-p-n-pmodp-where-p-is-prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\displaystyle\ \ {\rm mod}\ 71\!:\,\ 64! = \frac{70!}{\color{#c00}{70}\cdots \color{#0a0}{65}}\!\!\stackrel{\rm\ Wilson_{\phantom{ I_I}}}\equiv\!\!\!\! \frac{-1}{\color{#c00}{(-1)}\cdots \color{#0a0}{(-6)}}\equiv \frac{-1}{720}\equiv\frac{70}{10}\equiv 7$

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. $71$ happens to be a prime. We have Wilson's theorem telling us that for a prime $p$ we have
$$
(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{p}.
$$
So $70!\equiv-1\pmod{71}$ without further ado. Here
$$
70!=64!\cdot65\cdot66\cdot67\cdot68\cdot69\cdot70\equiv
64!(-6)(-5)(-4)(-3)(-2)(-1)=64!\cdot6!\pmod{71}.
$$
Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You can use [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) to get:

$$70! \equiv -1 \mod 71$$

Then use that $70! = 64!\times 65\times...\times70$.