# Finding out remainder

Tags: number-theory

I need to find the remainder when $ 20!+20^{23} $ is divided by 23 . .please help. Wilson theorem involved , Fermat's little theorem involved as well.

Comment: Yes, you know the right ingredients. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/99879/589.

Answer (score 2):

Using Fermat's Little Theorem:
 $$20!+20^{23} \equiv 20!+20 \pmod{23}$$ 
Let's now solve this equation:
 $$20!+20 \equiv x\pmod{23}$$

$$(22*21)(20!+20) \equiv (22*21)x\pmod{23}$$

$$22!+(22*21)20\equiv (22*21)x\pmod{23}$$
Using Wilson's Theorem:
 $$-1+(22*21)20 \equiv (22*21)x\pmod{23}$$

$$-1+(-1*(-2))(-3) \equiv (-1*(-2))x\pmod{23}$$

$$-7\equiv 2x\pmod{23} $$

$$8 \equiv x\pmod{23}$$