# Why is $(p-2)! \textrm{ mod } p$ always 1 if $p$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

After running some test on my computer I found that when you have a prime $p$, then $(p-1)!  \textrm{ mod } p$ always equals to $p-1$ and that $(p-2)!  \textrm{ mod } p$ always equals to $1$.

Why is this the case? (I don't need answers on *both* findings, just one as when I know that why $(p-2)!  \textrm{ mod } p$ always equals to $1$ then just by multiplying it by $p-1$ we get $(p-1)! \textrm{ mod } p =p-1$ and vice versa).

Comment: [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) states that $(n-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{\! n}$ iff $n$ is prime.

Comment: @user26486 Why not expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: More generally, [Closed form for $(p-n)!\pmod{p}$ where $p$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99876/318073).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) states ($n\ge 2$):  $$(n-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{\! n}\iff n\text{ is prime},$$

which can be restated as ($n\ge 2$): $$(n-2)!\equiv 1\pmod{\! n}\iff n\text{ is prime},$$

because $$(n-1)!\equiv -1\iff (n-2)!(n-1)\equiv -1$$

$$\iff (n-2)!(-1)\equiv -1\stackrel{:(-1)}\iff (n-2)!\equiv 1\pmod{\! n}$$

Comment: do you also know why $(p-3) \textrm{ mod } p = (p-1)/2$?

Comment: @HéctorvandenBoorn $$(p-2)!\equiv 1\iff (p-3)!(p-2)\equiv 1\iff (p-3)!(-2)\equiv 1-p$$   

$$\stackrel{:(-2)}\iff (p-3)!\equiv \frac{1-p}{-2}\equiv \frac{p-1}{2}\pmod{\! p}$$

Comment: We're assuming $p\ge 3$ here, of course. In the answer above there is no such restriction.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but still...

$\forall 0 < k < p, \exists! l : kl \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

$k^2 \equiv 1\pmod{p}, \Rightarrow k \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$

So if you take all remainders there will be 1, -1, and pairs of mutually reciprocal, so product will be -1.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^{p-1}-1$ has roots in $\Bbb Z_p^\times$, we may write $$x^{p-1}-1=(x-1)(x-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-(p-1))$$ Comparing coefficitents we get that $$-1=(-1)^{p-1}(p-1)!=(p-1)!$$ Noticing that $p-1\equiv_p -1$, we can divide both sides by $-1$ to get $$(p-2)!\equiv_p 1$$